# Hibernate / JPA friendly Jackson Serializer supporting Jackson 1.8

Tags: json, hibernate, spring, rest, jackson

The custom `BeanSerializerFactory` in http://kyrill007.livejournal.com/2577.html is the only custom solution I found to allow directly throwing persistent beans to JSON via Spring 3.0, and it works, it only serializes non initialized (lazy) attributes / collections (this allows me to use the entity Pojo as a DTO, as I initialize only what I want, and what is not initialized, doesn't get serialized to JSON)

But this worked well with Jackson 1.6, and I wanted to upgrade to Jackson 1.8 to solve the issue with Java Generics (hopefully) and now that custom solution is not compiling.

So my questions are

- What is the recomended way to auto serialize Entities to JSON without the need of DTOs
- Is there an official Hibernate Aware Jackson `BeanSerializerFactory` besides the above
- I'm starting to fear that if it's that hard to find, maybe my practice is not the best one
- What is the recommended way to do RESTful Ajax then with Spring 3.0 MVC and JSON?

The problems to solve are

- Not serializing lazy attributes / collections automatially (as the custom code above does)
- Supporting Java Generics and some kind of a client side object schema / validation
- What works on get should work on save, and allow partial objects graphs to be returned safely

Is there Anything? do I have to manually write DTOs for every Entity?, this is so non productive

Comment: Here is one: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SO has lots of experts, you might consider also asking on Jackson users list. Kirill (author of the blog entry) is responsive, and there are other experts there as well.